# Pig: Sort json objects in a file without a schema

Tags: sorting, apache-pig

I have a pig script where I load some data, stream it through a function to get a result. The result is a list of json objects containg a field named `count`. Now I want to sort the list in descending order based on the `count`.

All the documentation I found online said I can use `ORDER BY` but for that I need to know the schema of the alias. Now, since this is an alias I am generating in the pig script itself, I am not sure how to do the `ORDER BY`.

So I am storing it in a temporary file and loading it again with a schema and doing the sort. But i think it is not a very good practice. Can someone tell me how I can do this without using a temporary file?

My script right now is:

```
DEFINE create_list `create_list.py` SHIP ('$STREAM_FILE_PATH_SYNTAXNET/create_list.py');

input_data = LOAD '$DATA_INPUT';

result1 = STREAM input_data THROUGH create_list;
result2 = GROUP result1 BY 1;
result3 = FOREACH result2 GENERATE FLATTEN(result1);

STORE result3 INTO '/tmp/summarize';

a = LOAD '/tmp/summarize' USING JsonLoader('count:int,parent_pos:chararray,parent:chararray,child_dep:chararray,parent_dep:chararray,child:chararray,child_pos:chararray');
x = ORDER a BY count DESC;
STORE x INTO '$DATA_OUTPUT' USING JsonStorage();
fs -rm -r /tmp/summarize
```

As I said, I want to store the sorted list directly into `$DATA_OUTPUT` rather than use a temporary file. How can i do the sorting?

EDIT: I tried `x = ORDER result3 BY $0` but the job failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order the relation from the function like this

```
result1 = STREAM input_data THROUGH create_list;
result2 = ORDER result1 BY $0 DESC; -- Note:You might have to use (FLATTEN(result1)).$0 instead of $0 if the tuples/bag are nested.
STORE result2 INTO '$DATA_OUTPUT' USING JsonStorage();
```

Comment: After reading the edit in the question I wonder whether the code above would work.